# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable error 2222222222222222

Tags: python

I am trying to convert Pi into fraction but I found a error so I dont know how to solve it.

```
pi = 141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006
    ans = 10
    for i in int(pi):
        if i.isint:
            ans += str("0")
        else:
            active = False
    s = str("3") + str(pi)
    print(f"{s} / {ans}")
```

Comment: You can get pi with `math.pi`, but remember to import the math library with `import math`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate an integer value. You could use the value as a string first. Then you can use isdigit() to check out if the given value is a number. And finally convert them to integers when you want to do the math.  You don't need to convert "0" to string, because it's already a string.

Below is an example:

```
    pi = "141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006"
    ans = "10"
    for i in pi:
        if i.isdigit():
            ans += "0"
        else:
            active = False
    s = "3" + pi
    print(int(s) / int(ans))
```

This returns 0.3141592653589793